# Getting the error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" when consuming an Atom feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, atom-feed

I'm trying to display my Github activity feed on my web site but am getting the above error.

I have increased the timeout in my web.config as follows.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" />
```

I get the error when attempting to load the feed into an XmlDocument as in the line of code below.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(rssFeedUrl); //get error on this line of code
```

Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post rssFeedURL here?

Comment: Sure, it's just the feed that Github gives you for your activity.

https://github.com/DomBurf.atom/

Comment: I'm guessing therefore that there's nothing wrong with the code so maybe it's a config issue. What httpruntime values do you have in your config? Anything else that might be causing mine to fail but yours to work?

Comment: I think you have to remove executionTimeout="90" and then try.